# How to write XML file in append mode

Tags: android, xml

I'm trying to write a list of contacts to an XML file using [Simple XML framework](http://simple.sourceforge.net) ,according to the [Loose object mapping tutorial](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php#loosemap). And I want something like this

```
<ContactsList>
    <Contact id="1">
        <name>John Doe</name>
        <address>Somewhere</address>
    </Contact>
    <Contact id="2">
        <name>Homer Simpson</name>
        <address>Somewhere</address>
    </Contact>
    <Contact id="3">
        <name>Flash McQueen</name>
        <address>Somewhere</address>
    </Contact>
</ContactsList>
```

This is my `Contact.java`

```
public class Contact {
    @Attribute(name = "id") 
    public int id;      

    @Element(name="Nom")                
    String name;         

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setId(int id){
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

And this is how I make the call for all contacts

```
Serializer serializer = new Persister();
ContentResolver cr = c.getContentResolver();
Cursor cu = cr.query(URI, null, null, null, null);

taille = cu.getCount();          
if (taille > 0) {                             
// Loop over all contacts
Contact [] contact = new Contact[taille];
int k = 0;
while (cu.moveToNext()) {   
    name = cu.getString(cu.getColumnIndex(DNAME));
    id = cu.getString(cu.getColumnIndex(ID));  

    contact[k] = new Contact();
    contact[k].setName(name);
    contact[k].setId(id);        
    serializer.write(contact[k], xmlFile);
    k++;
    }
}
```

The problem is, I only get the last contact stored, seems like file is being crushed over while looping. I'm now looking for a way to write in `xmlFile` in append mode. I can't find a way to write in append mode with `serializer.write` method. Or there is better way to do what I want?

Comment: One piece of code is missing: Where do you get the object serializer ?

Comment: While I don't know if that's necessarily the issue you are having I think XML documents should have only one root element.

Comment: @Giuseppe What do you mean? `Serializer serializer = new Persister();` is just before the `contentResolver` call. I've edited the first post.

Comment: @Mike you're right, I edited my first post. How can I get this working?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use the java's libraries that needs for your purposes.
Keep in mind that I used that on standalone java application so you have to check if there are feasible for Android programming too.
General speaking, there are several ways to browse and/or write an XML, Java has 3 different methods (for what I know): **DOM** librariy, **SAX** library, **STAX** library 
 If the document it's not too long Dom fits your purposes, otherwise use sax or stax that are event oriented libraries indicated to use less memory (and because you're developing for mobile devices I guess it's better).
 Hope it helps